# How to send aspx page from API as a response?

Tags: c#, html, sql, xml, api

I am trying to send an aspx file as a response to my API. But I am able to send the URL of the file but i am not able to read the content in file and send it. Here i have a button "View Reports", when some one clicks on this button it will call an API that is need to send an aspx page with the data in response.

```
public dynamic ViewReports()  //(Request request)
{
    try
    {
        objDPSReturnData = CheckSessionAvailable();
        if (objDPSReturnData.ReturnFlag == "S")
        {
            var mapPath = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;
            mapPath = mapPath + ("ViewReports\\" + "ViewReportNew.aspx");
            return mapPath;
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you need to send the data this way?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do this in following sequence:

1. Process the data and create `aspx` page (which you want to send in API response)
2. Save `aspx` page at some location on server.
3. Return the URL of the `aspx` page as response in UI.
4. Then let the client redirect to this `aspx` page.